# Having an error when im migrating in laravel

Tags: laravel, error-handling, doctrine, composer-php, laravel-8

This is what I get whenever I try to migrate but just yesterday it was running until I get an error. I think I updated something thats why the version dont match with laravel

Can anyone help me?

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\mamjbproject> php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2024_01_16_100459_remove_default_value_from_detail_column_in_products_table
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase::connect(array $params) must be compatible with Doctrine\DBAL\Driver::connect(array $params): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\mamjbproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase.php on line 19

   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 

  Declaration of Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase::connect(array $params) must be compatible with Doctrine\DBAL\Driver::connect(array $params): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\mamjbproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase.php:19
     15▕      * @return \Illuminate\Database\PDO\Connection
     16▕      *
     17▕      * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     18▕      */
  ➜  19▕     public function connect(array $params)
     20▕     {
     21▕         if (! isset($params['pdo']) || ! $params['pdo'] instanceof PDO) {
     22▕             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Laravel requires the "pdo" property to be set and be a PDO instance.');
     23▕         }


   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException 

  Declaration of Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase::connect(array $params) must be compatible with Doctrine\DBAL\Driver::connect(array $params): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection
  at C:\xampp\htdocs\mamjbproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase.php:19
     15▕      * @return \Illuminate\Database\PDO\Connection
     16▕      *
     17▕      * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     18▕      */
  ➜  19▕     public function connect(array $params)
     20▕     {
     21▕         if (! isset($params['pdo']) || ! $params['pdo'] instanceof PDO) {
     22▕             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Laravel requires the "pdo" property to be set and be a PDO instance.');
     23▕         }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\mamjbproject\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Run.php:510
      Whoops\Run::handleError("Declaration of Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase::connect(array $params) must be compatible with Doctrine\DBAL\Driver::connect(array $params): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection", "C:\xampp\htdocs\mamjbproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase.php")

  2   [internal]:0
      Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()
```

PS. I was trying to make simple crud inventory system

I tried to update composer, update the Doctrine DBAL package, clear config cache, and try migrating again and again.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What makes you think that this problem is directly related to Composer itself?

Answer (score 1):

Update the doctorine dbal from your composer.json
update it to v3 it will be solved.

```
"doctrine/dbal": "^3.0"
```